# How can I use CSS transitions to animate a responsive layout's vertical orientation?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-transitions

I am trying to figure out a way to smoothly animate a responsive change to some elements' `display` property when the browser size reaches a certain breakpoint. I would like to use CSS transitions, but they do not apply to the `display` property so I may have to figure out a workaround. To be clear, I am only having trouble animating changes to the vertical orientation of elements that were previously arranged horizontally. Other, simple, responsive animations have been set up without issue.

[Here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/brianjsullivan/ULvqT/)

In that example, I have set up effective transitions for the div dimensions that activate at given breakpoints. The final (smallest window) transition causes the divs to line up vertically. At first, this was achieved by simply changing the divs from `display:inline-block;` to `display:block;`. However, this could not be animated using CSS transitions, so I tried an alternative method. The alternative involved changing the divs from `position:relative;` to `position:absolute;` and adjusting their `top` properties. I thought CSS transitions would be able to effectively animate the change in `top` but that does not seem to happen.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to know ?Please describe easy way.Hope for the answer.Tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you change from relative to absolute. That can not be transitioned in any way.

Just try to keep your styles and change only numeric properties.

For instance, you can keep using relative position, and adjust the left and top values accordingly:

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {
    .box {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
    }
    #box1 {
        left: 165px;
        top:10px;
    }
    #box2 {
        left: 0px;
        top:170px;
    }
    #box3 {
        left: -165px;
        top:330px;
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ULvqT/1/)

Change a little bit the style to avoid the ugly behaviour in smaller screens

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {
    .box {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        margin-left: -77px;
        margin-right: -77px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    #box1 {
        top:10px;
    }
    #box2 {
        top:170px;
    }
    #box3 {
        top:330px;
    }
}
```

[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ULvqT/2/)

The problem came when the container width could no longer hold the 3 divs, and they begin to flow to another row.

Comment: Yes! That is the effect I am looking for. I am aware that changes to the position property are not applicable css transitions or transforms. I had originally achieved the orientation change by altering the `display:inline-block` to `display:block` at the smallest breakpoint. This created a correct orientation but was also not capable of being animated using only css. Your solution is elegantly simple, however - just leave position alone and adjust the top and left properties! Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add, however, that there is an unintended problem that arises as a result of this fix. If the window is reduced in size beyond the final breakpoint, the divs begin to align in wacky ways. I will see what I can do about that, as this fix seems like a great solution aside from this error.

Comment: I can't seem to identify what the problem is that's causing these divs to render all over the place at a certain point. When the browser window gets to be around 500px wide or less, you can see the undesired effect. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using positions or display use float element and give another break point so that you can have  a view how transition is going on..

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/822bX/

```
.box {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 5px;

}
@media (max-width: 680px) {
.box {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
    -moz-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -moz-transform 2s;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    -o-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -o-transform 2s;
    transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;

       clear:both;

    }
}
    @media (max-width: 380px) {
         .box {
        width:80px;height:80px;
        }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is intended to demonstrate. The issue at hand involves animating the transition to the vertical state. This seems to do nearly the same thing as my previous code, but to the left of the page rather than in the center. I am not seeing the final breakpoint carry out any animations.

Comment: "in big screen you have all the three div side by side but when you view it on tablet or phone it should get aligned in vertical order with a transition" is this what you want??

Comment: Yes, when viewed at the smallest breakpoint the divs should change from horizontally-oriented to vertically oriented. That alone is clearly doable a number of ways. The difficulty seems to be in animating the orientation change without using javascript/jquery.